# How to verify systemd is working

Tags: systemd, raspbian

The goal is to [configure systemd to start the minecraft service](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup#method-3-systemd) after boot.  A Raspberry Pi 4 was configured as Minecraft server per instructions:

> https://marctv.com/how-to-run-a-minecraft-server-on-the-raspberry-pi-4/

Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite
Minimal image based on Debian Buster
Version: May 2020
Release date: 2020-05-27
Kernel version: 4.19
Size: 432 MB

Commands to start Minecraft server:

```
cd ~/minecraft
./start.sh
```

If the screen command is issued after the start script, then server startup feedback is returned to the console:

```
screen -r minecraft
```

## ISSUE

```
screen -ls
```

returns

```
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-pi.
```

it should return:

```
There is a screen on:
    675.minecraft   (17/06/20 00:56:01) (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-pi.
```

A systemd unit file is configured:

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/minecraft.service
```

returns

```
[Unit]
Description=StartMinecraft
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/minecraft/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After unit file was configured:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable minecraft.service
sudo reboot
```

## QUESTIONS

- What BASH command can be issued to confirm that the service has been correctly configured and started?
- Why is a minecraft socket not returned by `screen -ls`?

## ThorSummoner Test Results

```
systemctl status minecraft.service
```

returns:

```
● minecraft.service - StartMinecraft
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/minecraft.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-06-16 16:56:24 EDT; 7min ago
  Process: 559 ExecStart=/home/pi/minecraft/start.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
 Main PID: 559 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 16 16:56:24 rpi4 systemd[1]: Started StartMinecraft.
Jun 16 16:56:24 rpi4 start.sh[559]: Starting Minecraft server.  To view window t
Jun 16 16:56:24 rpi4 start.sh[559]: To minimize the window and let the server ru
Jun 16 16:56:24 rpi4 systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: `systemctl status minecraft.service`, if the `Loaded:` line contains `enabled` that should mean the `WantedBy` target will start this service, additionally the `Active:` line should report the service is running, if it crashed, it will likely crash every time it's started.  this status output will show the last few lines of the systemd log, you can check more with `journalctl -u minecraft.service` and normal `less` commands like `G` (shift+g) will goto the end of this log. or reboot to test(P.S., I don't know of a good existing SO answer about this topic, otherwise I would have linked it here)

Comment: @ThorSummoner  Please consider promoting your comment to an answer.

Comment: It is likely that you need to include `Type=forking` in the `[Service]` section of your unit file, `systemctl daemon-reload` and bounce the service. Without looking at the script that is being referenced by `ExecStart` it's not clear to me what it is doing, but if it is launching a process and completing, you need to explicitly state `Type=forking` so systemd can track the spawned process and not the initial one.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl status minecraft.service
```

will tell you if the server is alive or dead.

To have screen list the Minecraft screen, you need to run it as the user who started the screen. This appears to be root, based of the guides you linked to.

```
sudo screen -ls
```

should do the job.